# Random Color in Embed Slash Command (Discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want my bot to put a random color for my embed on a slash command. I've tried using `RANDOM` but that doesn't work. Here's my code:

```
//I would usually do: color: 0x[hex code]
const randomcolorembed = {
  color: `RANDOM`, //This doesn't work
  description: `blah blah blah...`
};

bot.api.interactions(interaction.id, interaction.token).callback.post({
  data: {
    type: 4,
    data: {
      embeds: [ randomcolorembed ]
    }
  }
})
```

If anyone knows how to do this then please let me know, Thanks!

Comment: <Client>#api is for private reasons. Support for that will not be provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out a different way which worked a lot better:

```
const randomcolorembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setColor(`RANDOM`)
.setDescription(`blah blah blah...`)

bot.api.interactions(interaction.id, interaction.token).callback.post({
  data: {
    type: 4,
    data: await createAPIMessage(interaction, embed)
  }
})
```

I would also have:

```
async function createAPIMessage(interaction, content) {
    const apiMessage = await Discord.APIMessage.create(bot.channels.resolve(interaction.channel_id), content)
        .resolveData()
        .resolveFiles();
    
    return { ...apiMessage.data, files: apiMessage.files };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this little piece of code to generate a random hex code that will be used as the embed color:

```js
const randomcolorembed = {
  color: '#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16),
  description: `blah blah blah...`
};
```

Comment: It needs to be like `color: 0x[hex code]`.

Comment: Then just make it  `'0x'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16),` instead

Comment: I’ve already tried that and I got an error saying it’s not an integer